# Cant redraw UILabel after updating text

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to create a timer which updates a label every tick, This is what I have so far:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
    timer = new Timer ();
    timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler (TimerOnTick);
    timer.Interval = 1000;
    timer.Start ();
}

private void TimerOnTick (object obj, EventArgs ea)
{
   timerLabel.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString ();
   timerLabel.SetNeedsDisplay ();
}
```

But this doesn't update the label. In debug I can see that `timerLabel.Text` is being set, but I cant get the view to update or redraw.

How can I get my view to redraw after I update my `timerLabel.text`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The label is not being updated because System.Timers.Timer invokes the handler on a separate thread. You cannot change ui elements in a thread other than the main.

Enclose your handler code to be executed on the main thread:

```
private void TimerOnTick (object obj, EventArgs ea)
{
   this.InvokeOnMainThread(delegate {
       timerLabel.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString ();
       timerLabel.SetNeedsDisplay ();
   });
}
```