# UILabel text not being updated

Tags: ios, uilabel, asihttprequest

I am unable to change the UILabel text. The code for the the UILabel inside viewDidLoad is :

```
startLabel=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(75, 395, 200, 30)];
startLabel.text=@"Recording Sound ...";
startLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
startLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
startLabel.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];

[self.view addSubview:startLabel];
```

Later, if I want to change the label of the text with the following code, its not changing on the app :

```
startLabel.text=@"Searching Database ...";
```

or

```
[startLabel setText:@"Searching Database ..."];
```

The UILabel is not empty, I printed it out during debugging and it shows :

```
(gdb) po startLabel
<UILabel: 0x2c1a30; frame = (75 395; 200 30); text = 'Searching Database ...'; 
clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x2ae8f0>>
```

So, the text of the label changes inside the UILabel, but its not updated on the screen.

Can anyone kindly let me know what 
I am missing here ? Thanks.

Edit 1: I tried `performSelectorOnMainThread:` -  didnt work for me.
Edit 2: I am using `AVFoundation` and `ASIHTTP` classes to record sound and upload the recorded file here. Nothing else. Didnt use any thread.

Comment: Where are you updating the text (what method)? It needs to be on the same thread (see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000741/cant-redraw-uilabel-after-updating-text).

Comment: @Ben : aint that for monotouch ? Also, I am inside the same thread, just another function !

Comment: I totally missed that being a MonoTouch question, but I found a similar issue about needing to be on the same thread in a Mac forum that used performSelectorOnMainThread  (http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=463200), so I just wondered where you were calling it from.

Comment: @Ben : nope..not working.. :(.. any other suggestions ?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You may be facing an issue with threading as mentioned in the comments above.  If you have a method that runs on the main thread and does some activity (such as search a database), updates that you make to the UI will not be committed until the run loop gets control.  So, if you have a long, time consuming task going on on the main thread, run this code after setting the text of the label:

```
- (void)doSomethingTimeConsuming
    ... consume some time ...
    ... set text of label ...
    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.5]];
    ... continue long operation ...
}
```

This should flush out any UI changes that you have made.  Although this may be a sensible and functional hack, it doesn't beat the alternative.  I highly suggest that you perform your app's time consuming tasks on a background thread, and update the UI through the main thread using `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`. See Apple's page on [iOS Thread Management](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Here's what I am doing inside the app/view. I am using AVFoundation to record some sound and using ASIHTTP class to upload the recorded sound. nothing special.... In the function that uploads the file (a custom function) , I am initially writing the code to change the label. Nothing works. I even tried performSelectorOnMainThread ...didnt work. Do you think the recording/uploading qualifies as a separate thread ? Please suggest what I can do. Thanks.

Comment: [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] .. thingy worked.... the other alternate didnt... thanks a bunch.. :) you just made my day !

Comment: Thanks, I was having a similar problem but the `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` solution worked great for me. Traced back the problem to the fact that a UI update was getting triggered (but not showing up) from a code block that was set to run after an asynchronous URL request finished. I might even suggest making that solution appear more prominently in your answer so that people don't miss it, as it's currently the accepted answer?

Comment: even `[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0]];` works for me (with 0 timeinterval)

Answer (score 50):

In my case the function that was updating was called from a touch recognizer on a thread, but the place in the function where I'm changing the value of the label's text property I put it back on the main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.someLabel setText:someString];
});
```

Comment: I was trying to refresh the text from a method invoked within the notification center and this solves the issue, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I had a UILabel showing a level number that would not update to the new level number on a UIViewController.  The only viable solution I could find that worked was to call setNeedsDisplay on the main thread of the view controller that owned the UILabel

```
-(void)changeLevelLabel:(int)theLevel {
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    self.levelLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",theLevel];
    [self.levelLabel setNeedsDisplay];
});
```

}

See http://iosdevelopmentjournal.com/blog/2013/01/16/forcing-things-to-run-on-the-main-thread/ for a more detailed explanation

Answer (score 3):

Mine's a bit more unexpected, though reasonable--just not something anyone thinks too hard about.

I'm supposed to update the `UILabel` when I receive an `NSNotification` that I fired somewhere else. However, **the notification was fired from a background thread** so even the listener methods that update the label's text are fired in the background.

If you're relying on an `NSNotification` to update the label, or any of your views, do fire the `NSNotification` from the main UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using `localize-Swift` cocoapod, If you set a `localized key` to the UILabel, The value will be set after you set any text to the label.