# How to update UILabel?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, uilabel

**.h file:**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *frequencyDetailLabel;
```

**.m file:**

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    //LOCALIZATION
    ..
    self.frequencyDetailLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Select", nil);
}
```

Then later in my code I try changing the text:

```
self.frequencyDetailLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Done", nil);
```

Things I have done so far:

- Made sure the `IBOutlet` connection is working properly.
- Instead of changing the text, I tried changing the `textcolor` and it worked.
- Check if the `UILabel` was null/nil, it is not.
- Made sure both were pointing at same UILabel
- In my localizable.strings, both Keys exists.

Anything else I should try?

Edit:

**unwind method**

```
- (IBAction)unwindFromFrequencyViewController:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
if ([segue.sourceViewController isKindOfClass:[FrequencyTableViewController class]]) {

    FrequencyTableViewController *frequencyViewController = segue.sourceViewController;

    // if the user clicked Cancel, we don't want to set a frequency (skips code)
    if (frequencyViewController.frequency) {
        NSLog(@"THIS RAN");
        self.howOften = frequencyViewController.frequency;
        if ([frequencyViewController.frequency intValue] == 1) {
            NSLog(@"THIS RAN1");
            self.frequencyDetailLabel.text = @"Every day";
            return;
        } else {
            NSLog(@"THIS RAN2");
            self.frequencyDetailLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Done", nil);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried setting it to "Done" in the `viewWillAppear` to see if the "Done" really exists?  IF it works there for "Select" and does not for "Done" then your problem resides elsewhere.

Comment: 'Later in my code' Where exactly?

Comment: This probably won't solve your problem, but your `IBOutlet` should most likely be `weak` instead of `strong`. More on that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7678469/should-iboutlets-be-strong-or-weak-under-arc

Comment: @Putz1103 putting done in `viewWillAppear` does work. I do not think the problem is in the localizable.strings as I mentioned in question.

Comment: If it works there and doesn't in the other then you are likely trying to update the text from a background thread.  All UI updates need to be in the main thread.

Comment: @duci9y Later is an unwind method from another controller. I added `NSLog` to make sure the code was running and it did. Tried changing the `textcolor` in the same location and it worked. :(

Comment: @Putz1103 How would I check on what thread it is being called from?

Comment: Set a breakpoint, then while at that break point look at the call stack.  It will have a method hierarchy as well as what thread that hierarchy is running in.  If it's not thread 1 then you have a problem and need to asynchronously call to the main thread to update your UI.

Comment: @Putz1103 It is running from thread 1 :(

Comment: Thread 1 is not the main thread. I don't think it's running at thread 1 since you say it's an unwind segue. Thread 0 is the main thread.

Comment: @duci9y thanks, I will try and figure out how to call from main thread, have never done that before.

Comment: No no, if it's an unwind, it's **definitely** in the main thread. Could you post your unwind action please?

Comment: @duci9y posted on question since it is too long for comment here.

Comment: Put log statements logging your label before 'this ran2' and after you set 'Done'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58435/discussion-between-espitia-and-duci9y).

Answer (score 1):

Found solution in another question: [UILabel text not being updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835472/uilabel-text-not-being-updated)

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     [self.someLabel setText:someString];
});
```